# Coordinate change to use in Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I've been puzzled by the following exercise:

> Considering the set
>
> $$D = \left\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^3: 1<x+y<2; 0<x<y \right\}$$
>
> and the function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y) = (y^2-x^2)\cos(x+y)^4$. Calculate $\int_Df$, using an appropriate change of coordinates.

I've tried using polar coordinates to no avail (perhaps wrongly?). I'm guessing I have to use some other sort of coordinate system I'm unfamiliar with. Which one, then?

Comment: Perhaps you could try a linear change in coordinates, if you haven't already: $x=Au+Bv$ and $y=Cu+Dv$ where $A,B,C,D$ are constants.

Comment: For example, $u=y+x$ and $v=y-x$ might work out nicely. I haven't tried it, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the change $u=x+y$ and $v=-x+y$. So, jacobian reads $dxdy=\frac{1}{2}dudv$ and new variables vary $1<u<2$ and $0<v<u$. Then, your integral

$$\int\int_D (y^2-x^2)\cos(x+y)^4dx\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2\int_0^uv\,u\,\cos u^4\,dv\,du=\frac{1}{4}\int_1^2u^3 \,\cos u^4du=\frac{\sin 16-\sin 1}{16}$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But, you did make a mistake. $1<u<2$ and not $0<u<2$. So, the result should be $\frac{1}{16}(\sin(16)-\sin(1))$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I 've just changed.